# Sitecore 10: "Permission Denied" Error After Setting "Require Login" with Azure SSO

Tags: login, permissions, sso, sitecore-login

I have successfully set up `Azure SSO` on my `Sitecore 10` instance. However, I'm encountering an issue with restricting access to certain pages.

**Steps I followed:**

- Set up Azure SSO - This is working correctly.
  Used the Security Editor to apply `Require login` to specific items for the `default/anonymous` user.
- Expected Behavior: When an unauthenticated user tries to access these pages, they should be redirected to the login page.
- Actual Behavior: Instead of redirecting to the login page, it displays an error: `Permission to the requested document was denied.`

Could someone guide me on how to correctly set up page restrictions in this scenario? Is there an additional configuration step I am missing to ensure users are redirected to the Azure SSO login page instead of seeing a permission error?